# Rewriting url conditionally and making everything lowercase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, I've urls like this: `https://foobar.com/blog?category=Foo+Bar` , where the actual get parameter value may or may not have plus( + ) character in it.

What I'm trying to do is first make parameter value lowercase, in all cases, and then, if parameter value contains plus character( + ), replace it with hyphen.

In the end, I'm trying to get `https://foobar.com/blog?category=Foo+Bar` rewritten to `https://foobar.com/category/foo-bar`

This is what I got so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([^/]+)+([^/]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) /category/%1-%2? [R=301,L]
```

Now, that's somewhat close, but it actually rewrites `https://foobar.com/blog?category=Foo+Bar` to `https://foobar.com/category/Foo+Ba-r`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the lowercase see https://serverfault.com/questions/777577/apache-rewrite-all-urls-to-lowercase-if-contains-at-least-one-uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` at last of your htaccess file or in your `<VirtualHost>` section. Could you please try following then.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond https on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]*)=([^+]*)\+(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/${lc:%2}-${lc:%3}   [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Testing with `curl` command(with http but rule above takes care of `https` part):

```
curl -IL "http://localhost:80/blog?category=Foo+Bar"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/category/foo-bar
```

Comment: made minor adjustment to it: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([^+]*)\+(.*+)$`

Comment: @Milos, sorry, didn't see that, could you please check it now, if this helps you?

Comment: `.*+` is same as `.*` here